# Can mirrors reflect destructive lasers or do they absorb the energy and would get destroyed themselves?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, laser, interference

There is much talk of using lasers to bring down drones.  That talk is followed by talk of protecting the drones by surfacing them with mirrors.

Would that work or does light falling on a mirror impart all its energy to the mirror first before it can get re-emitted?

I am aware that lasers themselves use internal mirrors to reflect the light so it would seem that if lasers don't destroy themselves then the energy is not absorbed: or lasers are cooled, I don't know which is the case.

There are two questions here really: the Prime question is about the possible efficacy of protecting a drone by mirror surfacing.

The more general 'underneath' question regards reflection of light. Is it so that all light falling on a surface must be absorbed by that surface before it can be 'reflected' ?

It is my belief that it must.  That 'reflection' is in fact re-emission.

Comment: Note that the 'destructive laser' likely had some mirror that allowed only a small portion of the beam out of the cavity. So, it depends on the mirror.

Comment: Mirrors generally have impurities, which a destructive laser will exploit. Still, I’ve pondered this exact question as well, so curious to see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

High power lasers often have mirrors designed for the task. For example a common laser for cutting metal is a CO$_2$ laser. It may have hundreds of watts in the beam. The beam is in the far infrared, at $10.6 \mu$m.

These laser may use a copper mirror with water cooling. A special grade of oxygen free high conductivity copper is used for better thermal properties. This is softer than regular copper. Even though the mirror may be a couple inches thick, you treat it gently. It helps to think of it as wet clay. Dropping it would bend it a wavelength or so and ruin it.

The mirror has an highly reflective dielectric coating tuned to $10.6 \mu$m. Reflectivity and absorption at other wavelengths doesn't matter. A finger print on the mirror would absorb at $10.6 \mu$m, and ruin the mirror.

The other end might have a ZnSe or GaAs transparent window. Again with a good coating. These materials are transparent at the right wavelength and have good thermal properties.

This illustrates the idea. Military lasers generally use other wavelengths.

A laser has to work at one wavelength. To avoid being shot down, a drone might want to reflect wavelengths from all possible high power lasers.

Comment: And those high reflectivity dielectrics are really good at one angle of incidence, and not nearly as good anywhere away from that.